# How to rename values in a column of data which appear less than x times in R?

Tags: r

I want to rename some values in a column of my data which appear less than 5 times.

```
     Var1   Var2
1     A    High
2     A    High
3     A    High
4     B    High
5     B    Med
6     B    Vlow
7     C    Vlow
8     C    Low
9     C    Low
10    C    Low
11    A    High
12    B    Hlow
13    C    Med
14    A    Low
15    A    Low
```

So in this case I want to rename the values of `Var2` column to "other" which appear less than 5 times (`Hlow`, `Med`, `Vlow`). The expected result should be:

```
   Var1  Var2
1     A  High
2     A  High
3     A  High
4     B  High
5     B Other
6     B Other
7     C Other
8     C   Low
9     C   Low
10    C   Low
11    A  High
12    B Other
13    C Other
14    A   Low
15    A   Low
```

Here is the `dput()` of my dataframe:

```
structure(list(Var1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    Var2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("High", "Hlow", "Low", "Med", 
    "Vlow"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Var1", "Var2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Both columns are categorical variables (factors).

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Subset based on criteria and overwrite the values. Something along the lines of `x[x$count < 5, "value"] <- NA`. If you mean appearing in 5 rows, then you have to first count the number of occurrences. As @agstudy said, you need to provide a working example.

Comment: Cheers guys, I did, would you please take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Var2` is a `factor` you can use Hadley's new `forcats` package:

```
nlevels_to_keep <- sum(table(df$Var2) >= 5)
df$Var2 <- forcats::fct_lump(df$Var2, n = nlevels_to_keep)
df
#   Var1  Var2
#1     A  High
#2     A  High
#3     A  High
#4     B  High
#5     B Other
#6     B Other
#7     C Other
#8     C   Low
#9     C   Low
#10    C   Low
#11    A  High
#12    B Other
#13    C Other
#14    A   Low
#15    A   Low
```

### Explanation

The `fct_lump()` function *lumps together least/most common levels into "other"*. A positive value for parameter `n` specifies to keep the most common ("top") `n` levels.

To get the top n levels which are to be kept we have to count the appearances of each level in `Var2` using `table()`. Then we look how many times the count is equal or greater to 5. Here, we are using the "trick" that `FALSE` becomes `0`and `TRUE` becomes `1` when converted to integer. Thus, `sum()` returns the number of `TRUE`s.

### Data

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Var1   Var2
A    High
A    High
A    High
B    High
B    Med
B    Vlow
C    Vlow
C    Low
C    Low
C    Low
A    High
B    Hlow
C    Med
A    Low
A    Low")
```

Comment: this package sounds cool but coud not install it.got this error messagepackage ‘forcats’ is not available (for R version 3.3.1)

Comment: Thanks very much for introducing this package. it makes my life much easier as I deal with categorical variables.

Answer (score 1):

Start by using `table` to determine the which values of `Var2` are less than your threshold.

```
freqs <- table(df[["Var2"]])
lowVals <- names(freqs[freqs < 5])
```

Now we can use `%in%` to index into `Var2` at the values that are less than `freq` and replace it with `Other`.

```
df[["Var2"]][df[["Var2"]] %in% lowVals] <- "Other"
```

Comment: @SinaPN I am glad you appreciated the answer, but on SO [comments just saying thank you are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment).  When you get 1 more rep you will be able to up vote, and then you can use that as a way for saying "thank you".